Why are complete graphs not considered strongly regular graph?
Recently I was reading about regular graphs and came across the definition of strongly regular graphs. It is defined as a strongly regular graph is a regular graph G = (V, E) with v vertices and degree k such that for some given integers $\lambda\geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$, every two adjacent vertices have $\lambda$ common neighbours, and every two non-adjacent vertices have $\mu$ common neighbours.
It seems to me that complete graph satisfies these conditions yet they are not considered to be strongly regular graphs. I read the Wikipedia article on the topic and did not find explanatory.
Furthermore, it will be of great help if someone could provide me with books or references for reading on this topic.

Who says they are not considered strongly regular? They certainly satisfy the definition. Maybe what you mean is that these cases are so trivial they never get mentioned because there is nothing interesting about them.

The definition requires a certain degree $k$. A complete graph is strongly regular only when $k=n-1$, but usually $k$ is chosen smaller exactly because otherwise it would be trivial.

Also, look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph.
You will find that "The complete graph $K_m$ is strongly regular for any $m$."

That makes sense. The equivalent definition (as given on Wikipedia) in terms of eigenvalue of the adjacency  matrix excludes complete graphs and that got me confused. Thank you for the explanation.

Wikipedia also mentions, "By convention, graphs which satisfy the definition trivially are excluded from detailed studies and lists of strongly regular graphs."
